# MYSQL UTF Characters mixup ü vs u

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a mysql table with utf8_general_ci encoding where I keep data in different languages mostly English, Turkish, Farsi, etc.
The problem is that the sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `qkw` WHERE `eword` = 'turk'
```

returns rows with both "turk & türk" values as result.

I have the same problem with indexing which treats ü & u the same. Is this a bug in Mysql or should I use a different encoding? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The different collations are documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html), including the effect you're seeing;

> To further illustrate, the following equalities hold in both utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci (for the effect this has in comparisons or when doing searches, see Section 10.1.7.8, “Examples of the Effect of Collation”):
>
> Ä = A
> Ö = O
> Ü = U

If you don't want that, you can choose a collation from that list that does not see them as equivalent, for example `utf8_swedish_ci`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the collation to utf_bin, so far so good :)

Comment: @MasoodHosseini The only downside with `bin` is that it (as far as I remember) is case sensitive.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson `_bin` collations use the binary code of each character to compare string. This made them case sensitive. And, this might have some unwanted effect while *sorting* on string columns (for example, when sorted using utf8_bin, the french word "élève" will appear *after* the word "zozo"). Depending your needs, this might or might not be  an issue [ for reference "é" is 0xC3A9, "e" is 0x65 and 0x7A when encoded as utf8; 0xC3A9 is clearly *greater* than the two others ]

Comment: Case sensitivity is a plus for me indeed and for sorting I can use a relevant function, yet the information you provided has been very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to use the `utf8_turkish_ci` collation.

It will distinguish between 'u' and 'ü' as you wish. It is (`_ci` suffix) a *case insensitive* collation:

```
create table t (v varchar(255) 
                          character set utf8 
                          collate utf8_turkish_ci);

insert into t values ("turk"), ("türk"), ("top"), ("twin");

mysql> select * from t order by v;
+-------+
| v     |
+-------+
| türk  |
| top   |
| turk  |
| twin  |
+-------+

mysql> select * from t where v = "turk";
+------+
| v    |
+------+
| turk |
+------+

mysql> select * from t where v = "TURK";
+------+
| v    |
+------+
| turk |
+------+
```

---

Being based on simply comparing the binary code of each character, Using `utf8_bin` will produce slightly different results. Not only it will be case sensitive, but the ordering will be different:

```
mysql> alter table t change column v v varchar(255) collate utf8_bin;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.24 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t order by v;
+-------+
| v     |
+-------+
| top   |
| turk  |
| twin  |
| türk  |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t where v = "turk";
+------+
| v    |
+------+
| turk |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t where v = "TURK";
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, very useful.